# insert data into a table with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I am trying to insert data into a table with a sub-query and I am getting error. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_merging (image_id,name,source,score)
SELECT table2.image_id,table2.name,table2.source,table2.score
FROM
    (
        SELECT a.image_id,a.name,a.source,a.score FROM master_table a
        WHERE a.image_id = temp_subset_table.image_id
    ) AS table2;
```

Error I get is

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table temp_subset_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a temp_subset_table reference in your query like:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_merging (image_id,name,source,score)
SELECT  a.image_id,a.name,a.source,a.score 
FROM master_table a
JOIN temp_subset_table ON
  a.image_id = temp_subset_table.image_id
```

Removed unneeded sub-query.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_merging
(image_id,name,source,score)
SELECT table2.image_id
     , table2.name
     , table2.source
     , table2.score
  FROM
(
    SELECT a.image_id
       , a.name
       , a.source
       , a.score 
    FROM master_table a
       , temp_subset_table
    WHERE a.image_id = temp_subset_table.image_id
) AS table2;
```

you have to temp_subset_table in inner select join